# Google Cloud - Load Balancer / Global Static IP blocked by China

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have recently experienced two incidents, where Global Static IPs are blocked in China. Out of 12, only two IPs are blocked while remaining are working fine. These two IPs have been working fine for more than 8 months now.

I don't know How Chinese Govt interprets these IPs (probably thinking Google Search Engine).

Any clues ? Why 2 out of 12 Ips are blocked? Is there a criteria? How do we keep ourselves not blocked in China ?

Can google support help with this? Can we get the global static IPs moved into our company name (whois info on the IPs) ?

We would have to go back to AWS if we cant get around this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This can happen on AWS, too, or anywhere outside the firewall. If your app really needs to work reliably in China, AWS is probably a better pick - they have a Beijing region. https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/

Comment: Why 2 out of 12 Ips are blocked? Is there a criteria?

Comment: No clue, ask China. Maybe those IPs were previously attached to something China blocked, maybe it's random, maybe they don't like your site and all 12 will be blocked soon.